# Node depth from octree location code

Tags: octree

In the Article [Advanced Octrees 2: node representations](https://geidav.wordpress.com/2014/08/18/advanced-octrees-2-node-representations/) it is stated:

> The AABB of the node can be stored explicitly as before, or it can be computed from the node’s tree depth stored implicitly inside the locational code. To derive the tree depth at a node from its locational code a flag bit is required to indicate the end of the locational code. Without such a flag it wouldn’t be possible to distinguish e.g. between 001 and 000 001. By using a 1 bit to mark the end of the sequence 1 001 can be easily distinguished from 1 000 001. Using such a flag is equivalent to setting the locational code of the Octree root to 1.

The location code is a 32 bit word. That is, `... 001` and `... 000 001` might be equal as the author says *iff* all the bits following the first example equals those of the second example.

How does marking the end of the sequence help us finding the depth of a node within the tree?

The author uses the example `... 1 001` and `... 1 000 001`. Does the first node have depth 1 and the second depth 2? If so, how do I know? The location code is a 32 bit word so the bits following "the end flag" can follow as `... 001 001` which is also valid node.

So what I really don't understand is how to store in a 32 bit word both the location code and the depth of the node within the tree.

Answer (score 1):

I just read this article and had the same question. I think the answer is that, by defining the root node to have the index '001', you can guarantee that the first (most significant) 1 bit you see in the location code indicates the root. So:

```
... 000 001 000 001 can be read as <root> <0,0,0> <0,0,1>, level 2
... 000 000 001 001 can be read as <root> <0,0,1>, level 1
... 000 000 000 001 can be read as <root>, level 0
```

Comment: basically you shift until you only have 001 or smaller (e.g. 000), the number of shifts till that happens is the number of levels you have.